# Does anyone have recommendations for a good task/time management tool?

Tags: time, time-management, task-tracking

Does anyone have recommendations for a good task/time management tool.

Ideally this would just keep track of programming tasks / the project and the time spent also the option to produce an end of week report would be advantageous

Comment: Look at the related list on the right, this has been covered many times. close++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at the lower end, for free software, there's [ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/)

Comment: You forgot to mention that it absolutely rules :)

Comment: For a free tool this is is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Good feature coverage, but wow, that UI is abysmal.

Comment: Somehow it is not working in windows 2008 environment when I keep files in the ftp site. It does APPCRASH every now and then

Answer (score 3):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ) is your friend too. FB6 is a great PM tacking tool, I've been using 5 to manage my team and I'm trying to pry the money for FB 6 out of those that hold the purse strings.

For open source/ 1 dev its free as well.

Comment: Joel has some amusing and informative thoughts on the topic here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/12/29.html

Answer (score 2):

A good tool with collaboration feature as well:
http://www.producteev.com/

Answer (score 2):

We have been using [Eylean](http://www.eylean.com/) for our project management. It has all the features you are looking for and then some. You will be able to visualize your tasks as post it notes on a task board, estimate how much time they will take and then track them in order to see how much time they actually take up. It might be little more than what you are looking for, but i really enjoy the software.

Answer (score 1):

JIRA has a log work feature. You log your work on a per task/issue bases. My boss rather likes the reports.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with a large team, Team Foundation has it all. Work item tracking (which can be tied to checkins and builds!), reports, all sorts of metrics. For a small organization though the cost is probably too high.

Answer (score 0):

[Voo2do](http://voo2do.com/) is pretty good. I've used it before and it's great because it's very simple to start, but you can use the extended functionality as needed. And there's an API, which can fill in the missing features.

- organize tasks by project
- track time spent and remaining
- add tasks by email
- publish task lists
- as easy as paper, but on the web 24x7
- supports software guru Joel Spolsky's Painless Software Scheduling method
- fancy-shmancy “ajax” interface
- API for custom applications

Answer (score 0):

For basic commandline task tracking I use http://wtime.sourceforge.net/ It's simple but effective but only has top level tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another vote for FogBugz.  Originally I bought it for managing client projects, but I've grown to use it for keeping track of almost everything to-do related in my life -- simple tasks, stuff to remember, small personal/home projects, books to read, etc.  It's feature-rich and has a handful of nice integration points, and while it's still very much software-type-task-oriented, it's handy.  Very reasonably priced for the value.

Answer (score 0):

For task management for myself - Outlook

- It's centralised
- I have to have my email open so I don't need to worry about yet another application
- Sync to server so I can get it anywhere I have a browser
- Sync to phone so I get reminders when not at the desk
- Emails can be flagged as tasks

For task management for a team - TFS 2008 with SP 1. There is some nice enhancements in there with alerting that makes a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Smartsheet](http://www.smartsheet.com) as a tasking and collaboration tool. It's pretty well based on the idea of a spreadsheet that you can add your own columns to. The sheets can be shared amongst team members, it sends you emails when anything changes, it has file share (without limit) - you can also give external people access so that they can raise bug notifications etc. that then get notified to the team. Works very well for us as it is SO flexible

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Task Coach](http://www.taskcoach.org), an open source, single person, hierarchical task manager that allows for time tracking, categories, reminders and much more.